# Android studio criar diretorios

Tags: android

Como posso criar uma pasta no android studio (para guardar imagens - meu projeto ira ter muitas imagens e gostaria de dividir em pastas ou pacotes para melhor organização) ? Se eu crio na opção directory ele criar a pasta real, mas não criar na arvore de pasta no lado esquerdo. Estava criando dentro da drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar na pasta assets, e lá criar sub-diretorios

Para carregar da pasta assets:

```
   try {
    // carrega a imagem
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("pasta1/img1.jpg");
    // Transforma em Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    //mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException e) {

}
```