# Manipulando imageView android

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma image view no android, gostaria de saber como posso realizar a troca desta imagem via código ?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim :

```
ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_id);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nova_imagem);
```

Ou

```
 ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_id);
Bitmap bitImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.minha_nova_imagem);
    img.setImageBitmap(bImage);
```

Saudações!

Comment: deu certo amigo, aproveitando você sabe como posso criar uma pasta dentro do drawable ou algo semelhante para poder organizar melhor ?

Comment: Amigo, se possível, poderia criar uma nova pergunta? Para que pessoas que venham pesquisar, encontrem com mais facilidade ! Obrigado!

Comment: eu criei, mas ninguem respondeu , vou pegar o link

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95576/android-studio-criar-diretorios